# Why do I get : 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'Image'?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get my python code to draw me a picture.
I'm having trouble editing pixels. Not sure why. How should I change certain pixels in my image?

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ball.py", line 64, in 
pixdata = image.Image.load()
AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'Image'
```

I wanted to use `putpixel()`, but that gave me the same error that I have now.
I have `pil` installed (checked with --version)

Fragments of code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

pixdata = image.Image.load()

for i in range(distance):
    pixdata[x, y] == (255, 255, 255)
```

I expected a picture to appear in my folder... but I get an empty picture because the pixel changing causes errors.

Comment: You'll need to open an image first - have a look at almost any other question on PIL https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2836621+%5Bpil%5D

Comment: @MarkSetchell I was planning on making an image from scratch. I have relevant code for that which isn't included

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do but you almost certainly want to start with `Image.new()` if you are creating an image... https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html